# MySQL database sync betwen two servers using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, synchronization

I have the same website on two different servers.
`Master Database - server1`
`Slave Database - Server2`

I want to make PHP script which will check for changes in master database and if found any it will syncronize it with slave database. I will set chronjob for that script so it will run every few minutes.

I found some scripts on Google but it doesn't work at all.
I tried using [PMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlsync) but I'm receiving:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant host - assumed 'host' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 57
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant user - assumed 'user' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 57
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant pass - assumed 'pass' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 57
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant base - assumed 'base' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 63
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant host - assumed 'host' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 79
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant host - assumed 'host' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 57
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant user - assumed 'user' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 57
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant pass - assumed 'pass' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 57
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant base - assumed 'base' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 63
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant host - assumed 'host' in /var/www/demos/pms/pmslib.php on line 79

Comment: Ah yes, the "it doesn't work" error.  Very familiar with that one.  If you want answers, let us know why it doesn't work and what error messages you are seeing, then we can start to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may not need to use PHP at all for this. MySQL has replication capabilities built into it that can be turned on.  See chapter 16 of the MySQL manual - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Right, making PHP do this would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: if you use phpmyadmin you can set up the replications there.. pretty easy to do

Comment: Thanks. But it will work viceversa? So if something change in slave database, i need it to be updated to master server.

Comment: Yes - you can set up Master-Master replication - http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication